# How to describe endpoint 'users/{id}' in openapi 3.0 if id could be either number either uuid?

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, openapi, code-generation, swagger-codegen

I have following open api 3.0 definition:

```
  /users/{id}:
    get:
      tags:
        - User
      operationId: getParticularUser
      summary: Returns a user by id or by uuid
      parameters:
        - name: id
          required: true
          in: path
          schema:
            oneOf:
              - $ref: '#/components/schemas/UserID'
              - $ref: '#/components/schemas/UserGuid'

...
components:
  schemas:
    UserID:
      type: int
      example: 1488
    UserGuid:
      type: string
      format: uuid
      example: acc84651-8913-4c6c-b3b6-7562b1344843
```

The generated code is:

```
@RequestMapping(
    method = RequestMethod.GET,
    value = "/users/{id}",
    produces = { "application/json" }
)
ResponseEntity<UserDto> retrieveUser(
    @Parameter(name = "id", description = "", required = true, in = ParameterIn.PATH) @PathVariable("id") GetParticularUserIdParameterDto id
);
```

---

```
@Generated(value = "org.openapitools.codegen.languages.SpringCodegen", date = "2023-07-31T15:59:31.035932800+03:00[Europe/Moscow]")
public interface GetParticularUserIdParameterDto {
}
```

The problem here that `GetParticularUserIdParameterDto` interface has no implementation so I can't implement this interface.

Is there way to fix it ?

Comment: `type: int` should be `type: integer`; other than that your OpenAPI definition is correct. Check if this change will resolve the codegen issue.

Comment: @Helen I tried to use `integer` instead of `int`. Also I tried to use `string`  - result is the same

Comment: Looks like a codegen bug then. Open an issue in the https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator or https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen repo (depending on which codegen you use).

Comment: BTW I use https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/tree/master/modules/openapi-generator-gradle-plugin

so I should use github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator

Comment: Bug is reported
https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues/16226